# danielgindi iOS Chart Can I have two different Yaxis scale on a combined chart

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios-charts

I have created a combined chart with line/bar.

[image]

now, bar chart and line chart using same y scale as left axis(0-5).

Can I have line chart remain with it but have bar chart stick to right axis scale(0-10)?

linechart yaxis scale from(0-5), barchart yaxis scale from(0-10).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I created the bar chart part of a combined chart like the one you are dealing with I did this:

```
    let data: BarChartData = BarChartData()                
    let set = BarChartDataSet(yVals: entries, label: “label text”)
    set.valueTextColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    set.valueFont = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 14.0)!
    let colors = [UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.redColor()]
    set.setColors(colors, alpha: 1.0)
    set.stackLabels = [“Option 1”, “Option 2”]
    set.valueFormatter2 = BarValueFormatter()
    set.axisDependency = Charts.ChartYAxis.AxisDependency.Right
    data.addDataSet(set)
    return data
```

And probably the line you are missing is:

```
set.axisDependency = Charts.ChartYAxis.AxisDependency.Right
```

Comment: Thanks for your inspiration. Since they updated, now it is  chartView.rightAxis.axisDependency.

Comment: You made my day. Spend some hours til I found your answer. :-)